# Apache2 cannot find tiles rendered with tirex

Tags: apache, xyz-tiles, tile-server, mod-tile

When I open the map, I can see in `tirex-status` that mod_tile triggers tirex and some tiles are rendered. But the map I open does not show the tiles I am looking for:

```
GET
http://my-site.com/tiles/my-map/13/4291/2802.png
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 517ms]
```

This is /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/my-site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   
   ServerAdmin my@site.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html

   ServerName my-site.com
   ServerAlias www.my-site.com
   LogLevel info
   LoadModule tile_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_tile.so
   #ModTileRenderdSocketName /var/lib/tirex/modtile.sock <- modtile.sock is not in there
   ModTileRenderdSocketName /var/run/tirex/modtile.sock
   ModTileTileDir /var/lib/mod_tile 
   ModTileRequestTimeout 5

   AddTileConfig    /tiles/my-map/          my-map
</VirtualHost>
```

I am wondering why the tiles cannot be loaded.